# Forcing wget to name files as URLs

Tags: wget

Is there a way to force Wget to save files with the url address they are downloaded from as the file names?

Suppose the files are found here:

```
fish.com/salmon/s1.jpg
fish.com/tuna/t1.jpg
```

And I want the **filenames** (not directories) to be:

```
fish.com/salmon/s1.jpg, **not** s1.jpg
fish.com/tuna/t1.jpg, **not** t1.jpg
```

I know I can use -O to force a particular filename if there's just one download, but suppose I have 10k files? I also know wget won't overwrite files.

If there's no way to save the files as the full url due to the '/', can I save them as something fairly close to the url, e.g. fish.com_salmon_s1.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

if you use wget -r http://fish.com/salmon/s1.jpg http://fish.com/tuna/t1.jpg  the output will be placed in fish.com/salmon/s1.jpg and fish.com/tuna/t1.jpg.

so, use the -r or --recursive switch.

or, if you want to modify the names while retaining hierarchy, you would be better off with a script like this:

`` cat filelist | while read f
do
    fout=`echo $f | sed -e 's/\//_/g'`
    wget "http://$f" -O $fout
done ``

this would substitute all slashes (/) with underscores (_)

hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Darryl, thanks for the answer! I think you misunderstood the question, however. I've edited it to be as clear as possible. Pardon my n00bishness.